How to get python out of the "raw" terminal mode?
(In Linux context) Entering terminal raw mode (to read mouse, Function keys etc) in python is easy:
import sys, tty, termios
fd=sys.stdin.fileno()
#tty.setraw(fd)
tty.setcbreak(fd)

But then I want to get back and use input() again. Unfortunately, there is no tty.setcooked() function. What to do?

Save the tty attributes returned by tty.setraw, and pass them to termios.tcsetattr to restore the previous settings:
tty_attrs = tty.setraw(fd)

# later, to restore
termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, tty_attrs)

On Python versions before 3.12, tty.setraw returns None instead of the old attributes, so you'll have to call termios.tcgetattr manually:
tty_attrs = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
tty.setraw(fd)

# later, to restore
termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, tty_attrs)


Might you want to flush Python's output buffer before changing the mode?

@MarkRansom: Probably, if you have anything in the buffer.

I have python 3.8 and I also use os.set_blocking(fd,False) . To get back, I used subprocess.run(["tset"]) , but now your code is more efficient.
